# How would one implement this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

The below block of code is a solution to a problem, where you need to find two elements of an array that add up to a defined integer (k)

```
# Solution 1:
def two_sum(lst, k):
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if i != j and lst[i] + lst[j] == k:
            return True
return False

# Solution 2:
def two_sum(lst, k):
seen = set()
for num in lst:
    if k - num in seen:
        return True
    seen.add(num)
return False
```

Comment: 1) English (seriously though looks like [tag:python]) 2) `(0...lst)`

Comment: `list.length.times do |i|` in Ruby. This is not Ruby code though.

Comment: As for #3 if you have already seen a number that is equal to `k` less the current number (`num`) then `num` plus that number would equal `k` just basic arithmetic.

Comment: No, it's not Ruby, but any reader looking for an efficient Ruby solution to this problem might consider the following: `require 'set'; def find_sum(arr, tot); targets = Set.new; n = arr.find do |n|; rv = targets.include?(tot-n); targets << n unless rv; rv; end; n ? [n, tot-n] : nil; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `def n_sum(ar, target, n);
  ar.uniq.combination(n).any?{|combi| combi.sum == target};
end`

Comment: @steenslag, yes, but for `n=2`, that's O(n^2), whereas using a set is close to O(n) since set look-ups are close to O(1).

Answer (score 1):

1. Python (with broken indentations?)
2. `for i in range(x)` is a Python way of iteration over the range from 0 to x-1. In Ruby the same can be expressed in several different ways, for example in the very similar way using for loop `for i in 0...x`, using iterator over range as `(0...x).each { |i| ... }` or even as `x.times { |i| ... }`.
3. `seen` contains numbers from the list (array) that are already checked. If `k - num` equals to any number in `seen` (let's name it `j`), then it means `j + num == k` - q.e.d. For example, let's imagine we have `lst = [1,3,4,7,11]` and `k = 5`. In this case, the algorithm will work as follows:

   step 1: `seen = []`, `num = 1`, `k - num = 4`, `4` is not in `seen` - we
   add `1` to `seen`

   step 2: `seen = [1]`, `num = 3`, `k - num = 2`, `2` is not in `seen` - we add `3` to `seen`

   step 3: `seen = [1,3]`, `num = 4`, `k - num = 1`. Voila! `1` is in `seen` already and this means we can give the positive answer to the initial question: there are two elements in the source array so that their sum is equal to 5...

Comment: @LilaLiu, please, [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped